# Is there a way to make equations aligned in a table with 'tabularray' package?

Tags: tabularray

I use `tabularray` package to make tables as it is very convenient. But now I find now way to make formulas in a table to align at the `=` sign.
For example
[image]

The formulas in this table have been adjusted to several lines. But they are not aligned at the `=` sign. Is there a way to make them align at the `=` signs?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx,amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
                  caption={test},
                  label={tab:test}
                  ]{
                    colsep=0.5pt,
                    colspec={X[c,1.2] X[c,4] X[c,4] },rowhead=1
                  }
    \toprule
     1&2&{{{hello}}} \\
    \midrule
      the first equation&{{{$[\ce{Ca^2+}]=-3.19301 \mathrm{pH}^{3}-5.11013 \mathrm{pH}^{2}- 991.914 \mathrm{pH}+10^{0.0420576 \mathrm{pH}+3.90459}-7521.77$}}}&{{{$[\ce{Mg^2+}]=-3.19301 \mathrm{pH}^{3}-5.11013 \mathrm{pH}^{2}- 991.914 \mathrm{pH}$}}}\\
     \hline[dotted]
     
    \bottomrule    
  \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

I hope to be this style:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "make formulas in a table to align at the = sign".

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your reminder. I modified my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

An advantage of using the `\qty` and `\num` macros in the way they're employed below is that it's very easy to turn on rounding. For instance, if and when you decide it's ok to round to 3 decimal digits (and hence not show 5 or even 6 decimal digits), all you'd need to do is to change `\sisetup{group-digits=false}` to `\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=3}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, mathtools}
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[caption={test},,label={tab:test}
                ]{colsep=0.5pt,
                  colspec={X[c,1.1] X[c,6] X[c,3.5] },
                  rowhead=1
                 }
\toprule
     1 & 2 & {{{hello}}} \\
\midrule
the first equation
& {{{$[\ce{Ca^2+}]=
  \begin{aligned}[t] 
      &-\qty{3.19301}{pH\cubed}-\qty{5.11013}{pH\squared}\\
      &-\qty{991.914}{pH}-7521.77\\
      &+10^{(\qty{0.0420576}{pH}+\num{3.90459})}\\
  \end{aligned}$}}}
& {{{$[\ce{Mg^2+}]=
  \begin{aligned}[t]
      &-\qty{3.19301}{pH\cubed}\\
      &-\qty{5.11013}{pH\squared}\\   
      &-\qty{991.914}{pH}
  \end{aligned}$}}} \\
\bottomrule    
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I once tested `aligned`, but it can't. I tested your code, and it was right. I made some errors before I didn't find and thought it can't. How stupid was I.

Comment: Why did you put `aligned` environment in `$...$` ? I see in the website of `https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath`, there is no need to put `aligned` environment in `$...$`

Comment: @Y.zeng -- There are two ways to address your question. First, do please note that  the interiior of an `equation` environment is in (display) math mode automatically; it would be a mistake to initiate (inline) math mode when one is already in math mode. Second, do see for yourself what happens if you were to omit the `$` symbols from the answer shown above. E.g., don't be surprised if you get the message " Package amsmath Error: \begin{aligned} allowed only in math mode.".

Comment: Why there is a need to put `aligned` in `$...$`? I never see this before.

Comment: @Y.zeng — why? Because you will certainly get an error message if you do not execute the `aligned` environment outside math mode. Maybe you don’t understand what `$` does? The character initiates and terminates (inline) math mode.

Comment: @Y.zeng - “I never see this before”. I’m afraid I have no knowledge of what you may or may not have seen until now.

Comment: I tested that `aligned` needn't `$...$` in other cases. For example: `\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align}

\end{document}`

Comment: @Y.zeng - As I noted earlier, some environments -- including `equation` and, yes, `align` enter math mode *automatically*. Others -- including `aligned`, `gathered`, and `multlined` -- do *not*.

Comment: Another question: I don't number auto numbering about equations, so I changed your code `\begin{aligned}` to `\begin{aligned*}` there was an error. So how can I get no auto numbering equations in the `tabularray` environment?

Comment: I know now. There is a difference between `aligned` and `align`. I seemed t same. I was wrong.

Comment: @Y.zeng - There is no such thing as an `aligned*` environment. Not sure why you're asking about suppressing equation numbers in the code above. Since the answer I provided employs inline math mode, not display math mode, it most certainly does *not* generate equation numbers to begin with.

Comment: Okay. I mixed `aligned` and `align` before. Thanks. May you teach me how to align equations at `=` for those that are located in different rows with `tabularray` package?

Comment: @Y.zeng - Please post a new query to ask a new question.

Comment: Please do not delete it. I got much from your answer.  Thanks a lot.